# how to implement angular-tour on a angular web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i'm trying to add a tour to a web app using the ng-tour plugin: http://daftmonk.github.io/angular-tour/
The example on the plugin home page is done on a single web page making it hard for me to figure out how to implement this on a angular web app.  I added the following to my  index.html:

my code:

adding the tour-step id to a view:

```
<div ui-view="portal" ng-show="$state.includes('portal')" id="e0"></div>
```

At the bottom of my index.html file:

```
<tour step="currentStep">
    <virtual-step tourtip="test " tourtip-element="#e0" tourtip-next-label="next" tourtip-placement="right" tourtip-step="0" ></virtual-step>

    </tour>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when the app routes to the portal view...  Should I add the ng-tour tag to the individual views HTML templates instead?  I tried that initially but also couldn't make it work.

Comment: Anything in your console? Did you add angular-tour to your module as a dependency? `angular.module('myApp', ['angular-tour'])`

Comment: https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour#virtual-steps

Comment: @adamdport yes I did add it as a dependency.  And no I don't see anything in my console.

Comment: "If you don't initialize currentStep in your controller it will be by default set to -1, which mean the tour won't appear on page load." Do you initialize `$scope.currentStep` in your controller?

Comment: Thanks @adamdport That made it work.  Please add it as an answer so you can get the bounty.  Also please explain to me how I can go about implementing this on multiple views?  Do I have to increase the current step in every new view's controller?  e.g. I want the first tooltip to appear in portal.html and the second in player.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you don't initialize currentStep in your controller it will be by default set to -1, which mean the tour won't appear on page load.
>   [-Angular tour documentation](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour)

So make sure you initialize `$scope.currentStep` in your controller.

Regarding multiple views, [the virtual steps section of the documentation](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour#virtual-steps) says you can define all of your steps in one spot and just target elements in different views using `tourtip-element="#element-from-another-view"`. Of course those views will have to be on the DOM when you get to that tip.